insert image in to docx freemarker template
The project uses java and Freemarker to create documents. The sequence of actions is as follows: a template (docx with freemarker markup) is loaded into the system, then the user selects the necessary template and a document is formed according to the selected template, and a document in docx format is also obtained at the output.
Now there is a task from the database to insert an image (company letterhead) into the document, depending on which user generates the document.
The following solution was found on Chinese websites, it is necessary to convert the image to base64 and transfer it to a template.
Previously, the docx template is converted to XML, it is changed to ${photo}in XML (so that images from base64 are substituted instead of ${photo}), and then the image is generated with dynamic replacement from the database.
But first I need to upload a template file with the docx extension to the system, the system only accepts it as input. For freemarker, we pass base64 image, we also tried to send the image to byte[], but in docx, when processing with freemarker syntax, all options are converted to a sequence of characters, an example in the attached photo.
And the image does not display in docx.
processing with freemarker syntax image in byte :

processing with freemarker syntax image in base64:

freemarker syntax:


Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text (using code formatting), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and many more reasons. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data. See [mre] on what code is required.
